# app keeps crashing on connecting to server

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

So I am trying to download apk file from the server but my app keeps crashing.
I dunno why I tried using a separate thread, runnable and now a ThreadHandler.

DownloadActivity.java:

```
HandlerThread handlerThread=new HandlerThread("test");
        handlerThread.setPriority(1);
        handlerThread.start();
        Looper looper=handlerThread.getLooper();
        Handler handler=new Handler(looper);
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    String url="theurl";
                    URL u = new URL(url);
                    URLConnection conn = u.openConnection();
                    conn.getContentType();
                    conn.addRequestProperty("version",version);
                    conn.connect();
                    int contentLength = conn.getContentLength();

                    DataInputStream stream = new DataInputStream(u.openStream());

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[contentLength];
                    stream.readFully(buffer);
                    stream.close();
                    File file=new File(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,"debug.apk");
                    DataOutputStream fos = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
                    fos.write(buffer);
                    fos.flush();
                    fos.close();
                } catch(IOException e) {
                    //  404
                }
            }
```

What is going wrong here?
Btw, I did add the internet permission in AndroidManifest.xml

logs:
2020-09-26 09:19:00.373 24449-24449/com.testapp.test V/Typeface: CurFontPath: /system/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf
2020-09-26 09:19:00.373 24449-24449/com.testapp.test D/Typeface: switch to android orgin ttf
2020-09-26 09:19:00.394 24449-24449/com.testapp.test V/Typeface: CurFontPath: /system/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf
2020-09-26 09:19:00.394 24449-24449/com.testapp.test D/Typeface: switch to android orgin ttf
2020-09-26 09:19:00.414 24449-24607/com.testapp.test D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2020-09-26 09:19:00.429 24449-24607/com.testapp.test I/DpmTcmClient: RegisterTcmMonitor from: com.android.okhttp.TcmIdleTimerMonitor
2020-09-26 09:19:00.434 24449-24607/com.testapp.test I/DpmTcmClient: RegisterTcmMonitor from: com.android.okhttp.TcmIdleTimerMonitor
2020-09-26 09:19:00.436 24449-24488/com.testapp.test W/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglGetConfigAttrib:612>: EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE
2020-09-26 09:19:00.476 24449-24613/com.testapp.test E/RenderScript: SETAFFINITY ret = -1
2020-09-26 09:19:00.477 24449-24612/com.testapp.test E/RenderScript: SETAFFINITY ret = -1
2020-09-26 09:19:00.477 24449-24611/com.testapp.test E/RenderScript: SETAFFINITY ret = -1
2020-09-26 09:19:02.157 24449-24607/com.testapp.test W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot add request property after connection is made
2020-09-26 09:19:02.158 24449-24607/com.testapp.test W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.addRequestProperty(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:577)
2020-09-26 09:19:02.158 24449-24607/com.testapp.test W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.addRequestProperty(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:186)
2020-09-26 09:19:02.158 24449-24607/com.testapp.test W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.addRequestProperty(Unknown Source:0)
2020-09-26 09:19:02.158 24449-24607/com.testapp.test W/System.err:     at com.testapp.test.SettingsActivity$1.run(SettingsActivity.java:60)
2020-09-26 09:19:02.159 24449-24607/com.testapp.test W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
2020-09-26 09:19:02.159 24449-24607/com.testapp.test W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
2020-09-26 09:19:02.159 24449-24607/com.testapp.test W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:192)
2020-09-26 09:19:02.159 24449-24607/com.testapp.test W/System.err:     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
2020-09-26 09:19:02.424 24449-24488/com.testapp.test W/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglGetConfigAttrib:612>: EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE

Comment: What's the error? Please show error log

Comment: post the error log along with the question

Comment: How do i get the logs?